# Does PGAdmin and DBeaver each run on its own CPU core?

Tags: postgresql

From reading on the web, if I am not mistaken, I understand that **Postgres** runs only on **one core**.

My questions:

- If I have 2 Postgres programs on the same workstation, one runs on PGAdmin and the other one runs on DBeaver, would Postgres use 1 core for PGAdmin and 1 core for DBeaver?
- Also, is there a function that I can use to check how many cores Postgres is using?

Comment: "Postgres" usually refers to the PostgreSQL server; pgAdmin and DBeaver are two different programs, neither of them is "Postgres". DBeaver is a Java application, which runs in a Java virtual machine, which can use multiple cores. pgAdmin is a Python application, which generally is single-threaded, so probably uses a single core. However, to access pgAdmin, you need a browser, which _will_ use multiple cores. PostgreSQL server _will_ use multiple cores. Now, why do you care?

Comment: Thank you for this information. I didn't know any of this.  I have a long program running on pgAdmin (with Postgres as the database). I was just curious if I were to break that program in half and have one half runs on pdAdmin and one half runs on DBeaver, would I gain efficiency by running two halves concurrently. Thank you again for taking the time to help!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gupta for editing my question to make it clearer!

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is happy to use all the available cores. What is (mostly) single-threaded is a single database connection. That is usually no problem, because on a single database connection only a single SQL statement can be executed at any given time (there are cursors that allow you to have more than one statements at the same time, but only one of these will be processed at any given time).

Since version 9.6, PostgreSQL has been supporting *parallel query*, which allows it to start additional worker processes for a single resource-intense query; so with the proper configuration, a single SQL statement can run on many cores.

Comment: Mr. Albe, thank you for taking the time to help me understand this issue.